# I can't receive boolean sent from rest java ws to my android app as JSONObject

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley

Well, I get `Validation:com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException:value false of type java.jang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject` error whenever I try to receive a boolean value, that is sent by a REST web service, in my android app using volley's JSONObjectRequest format.

I know that using StringRequest will be the easy way to solve this but I really wonder if there's another way to solve this.
My guess is that the primitive boolean value is the problem because it is not equevalent to a json object. so the exeption is thrown in the `onResponse(JSONObject response)` volley method.

here's the java REST web service:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Boolean validate(CreditCard card) {
            //instructions
    if(/* some conditions */) {
        cardList.put(card.getId(), card);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the android app code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_id = findViewById(R.id.id);
        et_num = findViewById(R.id.number);
        et_type = findViewById(R.id.type);
        et_ctrlnb = findViewById(R.id.ctrlnum);
        et_expd = findViewById(R.id.expdate);
        b_validate = findViewById(R.id.validate);

        b_validate.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == b_validate) {
            String request_url = "http://192.168.191.1:8080/RESTCardValidator/rest/cardvalidator";

            JSONObject cardDetails = new JSONObject();
            try {
                cardDetails.put("controlNumber", Integer.parseInt(et_ctrlnb.getText().toString()));
                cardDetails.put("expiryDate", et_expd.getText().toString());
                cardDetails.put("id", Long.parseLong(et_id.getText().toString()));
                cardDetails.put("number", et_num.getText().toString());
                cardDetails.put("type", et_type.getText().toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, request_url, cardDetails,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Validation:" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Validation:" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    }
}
```

as you see in the image the value true/false is received

First Screenshot-

[image]

Second Screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Isn't this `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` wrong? As you're expecting to be just Boolean not a json. Try removing this

Comment: No not at all, i've already tried the service in my navigator and it's the same as `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`

Comment: because you are getting boolean response instead of JSON

Comment: @ZaidMirza exactly, i'm wondering if there's a way to upgrade the response from a primitive type to the level of a json object